# SQL query giving error in pgrouting?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

SQL error:

> ERROR:  function point(numeric) does not exist LINE 4:
>   (ST_GeometryFromText(Point(53.34972 -6.26025)), 4326), 1000)
>                                ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

In statement:

```
SELECT o.name
FROM osm_point o
WHERE ST_DWITHIN(o.way, 
(ST_GeometryFromText(Point(53.34972 -6.26025)), 4326), 1000)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.StackExchange! Please edit your question to include what software you are working with.

Comment: using phppgadmin with postgresql, pgrouting and hstore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't ST_GeometryFromText(Point(53.34972 -6.26025)), 4326) have quotes around the WKT since the function expects a text argument? So this instead -

```
ST_GeometryFromText('Point(53.34972 -6.26025)', 4326)
```

which also removes the extra right parentheses that you had after the WKT.

Comment: Tried that too:

SELECT o.name
FROM osm_point o
WHERE ST_DWITHIN(o.way, 
(ST_GeomFromText('Point(53.34972 -6.26025)', 4326), 1000)

Comment: the 1000 stands for 1000 metres away

Comment: Did you get the same exact error? I would guess that your parentheses are not balanced. I don't see any reason for the left paren before the ST_GeomFromText function. So this - SELECT o.name FROM osm_point o WHERE ST_DWITHIN(o.way, ST_GeomFromText('Point(53.34972 -6.26025)', 4326), 1000)

Comment: I still see the left paren before ST_GeomFromText which is unnecessary, I think.